# Make Artemis Slave Replication Use SSL

Tags: activemq-artemis

In Artemis when using replication to keep master/slave pairs synchronized the data will be replicated to the slave using a 'connection'.

I want to ensure this replication connection is encrypted. I suspect that this is done by using SSL on the `connectors` section of the `broker.xml`. However digging through the guides/official docs does not explicitly state how this is done. Yeah I can go waddling through source code and play with settings and try and sniff the traffic just thought asking here might be a bit easier.

Lets assume I have just a master/slave pair for now(I know not good for split brain but lets keep it simple for now) and will be using static connection lists as UDP is not allowed in my data center I have the following setup.

```xml
<connectors xmlns="urn:activemq:core">
    <connector name="master">
        tcp://master:61616?sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=/d1/usr/dltuser/keystore/qcsp6ab2001.jks;keyStorePassword=1q2w3e4r;needClientAuth=true;trustStorePath=/d1/usr/dltuser/keystore/qcsp6ab2001_trust.jks;truststorepassword=1q2w3e4r
    </connector>
    <connector name="slave">
        tcp://slave:61616?sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=/d1/usr/dltuser/keystore/qcsp6ab2001.jks;keyStorePassword=1q2w3e4r;needClientAuth=true;trustStorePath=/d1/usr/dltuser/keystore/qcsp6ab2001_trust.jks;truststorepassword=1q2w3e4r
    </connector>
</connectors>
<cluster-connections>
    <cluster-connection name="amq-cluster">
        <connector-ref>master</connector-ref>
        <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
        <retry-interval-multiplier>1.1</retry-interval-multiplier>
        <max-retry-interval>5000</max-retry-interval>
        <initial-connect-attempts>-1</initial-connect-attempts>
        <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
        <forward-when-no-consumers>false</forward-when-no-consumers>
        <max-hops>1</max-hops>
        <static-connectors>
            <connector-ref>master</connector-ref>
            <connector-ref>slave</connector-ref>
        </static-connectors>
    </cluster-connection>
</cluster-connections>
<ha-policy>
    <replication>
        <master>
            <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
            <!-- what master/slave group is this broker part of, master and slave must match -->
            <group-name>nft-group-1</group-name>
            <!-- does the broker initiate a quorum vote if connection to slave fails -->
            <vote-on-replication-failure>true</vote-on-replication-failure>
            <!-- how many votes should backup intiate when requesting a quorum?-->
            <vote-retries>5</vote-retries>
            <!-- how long should the broker wait between vote retries -->
            <vote-retry-wait>5000</vote-retry-wait>
            <vote-on-replication-failure>true</vote-on-replication-failure>
            <cluster-name>amq-cluster</cluster-name>
        </master>
    </replication>
</ha-policy>
```

From my understanding the connectors will be used when forming the master slave pairs and then the replication will be done via SSL using the configuration from connectors section is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From my understanding the connectors will be used when forming the master slave pairs and then the replication will be done via SSL using the configuration from connectors section is this the case?

Yes, that is the case.

Comment: Can I create a pull request and add this to the documentation?

Comment: Pull requests are always welcome. If there is a problem with the pull request then it can be identified and discussed on GitHub.